# Problems runing Street pyghter - 1.2

Tags: pygame, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run [this project](https://www.pygame.org/project-Street+pyghter-1860-3264.html)
on my Raspberry Pi 4 but there is some errors, like some files missing, and variables not defined.

I tried to change and fix the problems but still not working.

Someone have a tutorial to build one from zero or a new version?

In every project creating my own or clone gaves me this error on the terminal:

`Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html /home/pi/Desktop/pygame/main.py:3: RuntimeWarning: use font: libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ImportError: libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) pygame.font.init() Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/Desktop/pygame/main.py", line 3, in <module> pygame.font.init() File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 59, in __getattr__ raise NotImplementedError(missing_msg)`

Comment: you can just watch any tutorial on pygame to understand the basics and then just recreate it from what You have learned, also maybe the project is written in an older python version while You use a newer

Comment: it gave me this error even in new projects

Comment: intersting, I don't know what it means and probably is the issue with source code, so just create Your own, it will help You better in that You will actually learn something, also things like errors should be put into the post via [edit]

Comment: ok, the actual issue seems to be with something related to font, could be a version issue, don't know about it, try pasting the last line of error in google and see if someone has had similar issues, or ask someone from the devs about this

Comment: I should try to setup again my Raspberry Pi Erasing the OS and installing again?

Comment: what? erm, probably not, I don't know really what to do, ask the devs of Street Fighter what to do

Comment: also in Raspberry Pi gave me this error with images `File is not a Windows BMP file`

Comment: It gave me this: `File "/home/pi/Desktop/lalogame/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png'))
pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file`

Comment: I already told you that errors should pe [edit]ed in to the post, second I have no idea what that error means, maybe try running the code on a windows machine or better yet search online what it means, I have no idea about this issue, as I said maybe ask the devs of this game or find maybe some discord server for pygame or sth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it in Raspberry Pi, setting it from zero, deleting all in the micro SD card and installing again Raspberry Pi OS, the problem was that I tried to install on the terminal the pygame but is already installed on Raspberry Pi, so probably was an error during the installation.